# Single selection in listview by button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, selection

Goal:
Need to make selection of a single row included button in the listview.

Problem:
**Don't know how to make a single selection in the listview when you are clicking on the button that is located inside of listview. In a simple explanation, when clicking on the button, no selection will be applied in the listview's row**

It would be great if selection is applied before entering button's method cuz i need to grab information from the single selection of the listview that should be sent to business logic.

---

```
private void btnBuy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

```xml
<ListView Height="242.47" Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="49.53" Width="435.22" Name="lstOrder" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="lstOrder_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" SelectionChanged="lstOrder_SelectionChanged"
        SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Article Number" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_articleNumber}"
                    TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderRightAlignedStyle}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_name}"
                    TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderRightAlignedStyle}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Sale Price" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_salePrice}"
                    TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderRightAlignedStyle}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Product Category" Width="auto"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_productCategory}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderRightAlignedStyle}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_quantity}"
                    TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderRightAlignedStyle}" />
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="btnBuy" MinHeight="20" MinWidth="50" Content="Buy" Click="btnBuy_Click" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

```
namespace MediaStore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Counter.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Counter : Window
    {
        private ManagerProduct _myManagerProduct;
        private ManagerCart _myManagerCart;

    public Counter(ManagerProduct pManagerProduct, ManagerCart pMyManagerCart)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        _myManagerProduct = pManagerProduct;
        _myManagerCart = pMyManagerCart;


        lstOrder.AddHandler(ListViewItem.UnselectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ItemSelected), true);


        UpDateGUI();
    }


    public void UpDateGUI()
    {
        FillDataInListView();
    }

    private void FillDataInListView()
    {
        lstOrder.DataContext = _myManagerProduct.GetAllProductList();
    }

    #region Tab Order - 1. Order

    private void btnBuy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnDisplayCart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCheckout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cvsOrder.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        cvsConfirmation.Margin = new Thickness(8, 8, 8, 17);
    }

    private void lstOrder_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {


    }


    private void ItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void lstOrder_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    #endregion

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not need to select the ListViewItem, you can get your dataobject from the `DataContext` of the `Button` and you don't need the data from other rows since you wanted a single selection anyway.

In the event-handler:

```
var data = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyData;
```

(*On a side note, that being said, do you need selection at all? If not use an `ItemsControl`*)

To make the `ListViewItem` select itself if the button is clicked you can use a `ItemContainerStyle` like this:

```xml
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Here is an alternative using an animation which preserves the selected item after the `ListView` looses focus (only works with `ListView.SelectionMode` being `Single` as it does not seem to be possible to clear the previous selection using an animation):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin, Mode=OneWay}"
                Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: 1. To be more specified, where exactly in the class Counter should this code "var data = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyData;" be applied?

Comment: ...I noted that the code belongs into the button event handler. `MyData` is the name of whatever class the items in your `ListView.ItemsSource` are instances of.

Comment: When you define "event handler", do you mean the different event from properties like "Click", "Drop", "PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp", "SelectionChanged" etc?
If yes, which event do you recommend me to use?

Comment: What else than the click event handler you already defined could i mean? Seriously...

Comment: Seriously... I also heared that definition between event and event handler are different depends on how you use it by coding or click and drop. Maybe you have the explaination?

Comment: Sorry, that sentence didn't make all too much sense to me. (By the way *"heared"* should be *"heard"*). Apparently my answer helped at least :)

Comment: @H.B.: I've tried a solution you've proposed using ItemContainerStyle and I'm having a lot of SelectedIndex changed events fired when I clicked button inside a ListView item. Why it happens, I need it only one time to be fired